# nancyfx and aspx

Tags: asp.net, nancy

Using NancyFX with asp.net -- no problem on the nancy side but I have some old code that would be easiest left alone in aspx using a customer control. So I need to be able to run a .aspx page? I'd rather no put it in a different web site. Can I run a .aspx page in iis within the nancyfx project by either exempting the path or using the aspx form engine or somethign?

Comment: what is the problem? where is the code which is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no. Nancy does not support the WebFormsViewEngine because, quite frankly, the baggage it brings along is the same that we wanted to leave behind us when creating Nancy.

However, you can run Nancy inside an existing ASP.NET Webforms/MVC application as described on our wiki https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Hosting-nancy-with-asp.net